# Trying to construct my game board - but running into an undefined ID problem

Tags: javascript, api

I'm trying to make my tic tac toe game board work but it keeps giving me the same error that '_id' in undefined in my api file. I'm not sure why it's coming out that way but i'm including my events file below it so that it can be compared. I've compared it to other people's code and it looks largely the same but it is spitting back the same error message every time.

```
const updateGame = function (index, value, over) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: config.apiUrl + '/games/' + store.game._id,
    method: 'PATCH',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + store.user.token
    },
    game: {
      cell: {
        index: index,
        value: value
      },
      over: over
    }
```

```
const api = require('./api')
const ui = require('./ui')
// const getFormFields = require('../../../lib/get-form-fields')

let gameOver = false
const board = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
let moves = 0

const onCreateGame = function (event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log('it was clicked')
  api.createGame()
    .then(ui.onCreateGameSuccess)
    .catch(ui.onCreateGameFailure)
  $('.box').show()
}

const onCheckWinner = function (event) {
  if (board[0] !== '' && board[0] === board[1] && board[1] === board[2]) {
    return true
  } else if (board[3] !== '' && board[3] === board[4] && board[4] === board[5]) {
    return true
  } else if (board[6] !== '' && board[6] === board[7] && board[7] === board[8]) {
    return true
  } else if (board[0] !== '' && board[0] === board[3] && board[3] === board[6]) {
    return true
  } else if (board[1] !== '' && board[1] === board[4] && board[4] === board[7]) {
    return true
  } else if (board[2] !== '' && board[2] === board[5] && board[5] === board[8]) {
    return true
  } else if (board[0] !== '' && board[0] === board[4] && board[4] === board[8]) {
    return true
  } else if (board[2] !== '' && board[2] === board[4] && board[4] === board[6]) {
    return true
  }
  return false
}

const onUpdateGame = function (index, player, over) {
  event.preventDefault()

  const clickedCell = event.target
  console.log($(clickedCell).data('cell-index'))
  api.updateGame(index, player, over)
    .then(response => {
      if (player === 'X') {
        $(clickedCell).text('X')
        player = 'O'
        $('#message').text('Nice move! Player O, your turn!')
      } if (player === 'O') {
        $(clickedCell).text('O')
        player = 'X'
        $('#message').text('Nice move! Player X, your turn!')
      } if (onCheckWinner(event) === true) {
        $('#message').show().text('Game Over!')
        gameOver = !gameOver
      } else {
        $('#message').text('Please pick a space that is unoccupied!')
        setTimeout(() => {
          $('#message').text('')
        }, 2000)
      }
      ui.updateGameSucess(response, index, player)
    })
    .catch(ui.updateGameFailure)
  //
  //
  player = !player
  if (gameOver === true) {
    $('#message').show().text('Game Over!')
  }
  //
  moves++
  if (moves === 9 && onCheckWinner(event) === false) {
    $('#message').show().text('Game Over!')
    $('#message').show().text('Draw!')
    $('#message').hide()
  }
}
//  api.onClickedCell()
//    .then(ui.onClickedCellSuccess)
//    .catch(ui.onClickedCellFailure)
module.exports = {
  onCreateGame,
  onCheckWinner,
  onUpdateGame
}
```

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to get `._id` of an *undefined* reference, at the moment you are trying to do it. Possibly because you are trying to call `onUpdateGame()` somewhere in your code, before the `store.game` reference is being loaded.

To prevent this error, you can first check that such reference exists, and only act when it's safe to do so.

For example:

```js
const updateGame = function (index, value, over) {
  if(!store.game) {
    // game not loaded yet, can't update it -> just return (keep trying again later, until it gets loaded) 
    return
  } 
  // at this point 'store.game' is loaded, you can access it's '_id'.
  return $.ajax({
    url: config.apiUrl + '/games/' + store.game._id,
    method: 'PATCH',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + store.user.token
    },
    game: {
      cell: {
        index: index,
        value: value
      },
      over: over
    }
```